# Dimensionality of a Transpose Vector

Tags: vector-spaces

This is mostly based on my lack of understanding of what transposition does to a vector. Say you have a vector $[1,2,3]$, it is clear to me why it is $1$-dimensional. After transposing this matrix, it would become $[1,2,3]^T$ . Is this vector also $1$-dimensional?

Apologies for the lack of formatting, it does not seem to allow me to include an image link to Latex formatting.

Comment: The former vector is 1 row $\times$ 3 columns, the latter is 3 rows $\times$ 1 column.

Comment: A line vector can be understood as a function $\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, you can consider a transposed (=line) vector as an operator that will act on non-transposed (=column) vectors as a matrix in this way: $(a \ b \   c)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=ax+by+cz$ and give a number as its result.

Comment: The definitive answer to your question is, yes, on the dimensionality point of view, a vector generates a 1D subspace and its associated transposed vector as well.